# How to hash text to md5/sha1 in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to convert text to sha1 in django. But, i'm not find the way how to do it if field attribut wrapped by the form.

This is my views:

```
def ubah_password_email(request, pk):
    #cek session
    if 'username' in request.session and request.session['hak_akses'] == 'user':
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk) #ambil id dengan get
        profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=user).first() 
        email_form = EmailForm(data=request.POST, instance=profile) #gunakan instance untuk mengambil data yang sudah ada
        users = User.objects.all()
        if request.POST:
            if email_form.is_valid():
                email = email_form.save(commit=False)
                email.save()
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            email_form = EmailForm(instance=profile)

        data = {
                'email_form': email_form,
                'object_list': users,
        }
        return render(request, 'ubah_password_email.html', data)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/simofa/logout')
```

This is my model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User) #digunakan untuk relasi ke model User (default) alias UserProfile adalah sebagai extending model
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('admin','Admin'),
        ('user','User'),
        )
    hak_akses = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES) 
    password_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    password_pckelas = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

This is my forms

```
class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password_email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('password_email',)
```

i'm trying using [this](http://www.bloggerpolis.com/2011/09/how-to-generate-a-django-password/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012616/python-md5-password-value) reference. But, i still can't convert text to sha1?

I'm very grateful for your input. So, please help me :)

Comment: No. Do not do this. Do not ever do this. Django has a very good built-in method of setting and hashing passwords which has been thoroughly reviewed by security experts, and even then they keep finding (and fixing) issues. Please read and follow the [authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/) docs, especially the section on [custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) if that's what you really need to do.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is correct - please follow his advice. From the looks of your code, you're trying to allow people to create other users. Django has built-in forms and views for doing these operations - use them.

Comment: I'm just curious about this technique. This is not for authentication. My code just to store password information for future email will be used to authenticate the email in other applications. That's it, not for authentication deffault because I have my own authentication. So, I need to know how to do a hash of the text to sha1 / md5

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want or need a second password field. But `make_password` allows you to generate a hashed password:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password

Source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L58

Comment: Yes i have try that documentation. But, how to encrypt it on field / model that wrapped by form?