# Django execute a function after django.contrib.auth.login

Tags: python, django, django-login

I am using Django's default authentication system to run my website. So whenever a user logs in in urls.py I have -

`(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),`

I guess django uses `django.contrib.auth.login` & `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` to login.

Now as part of some requirement I am needed to run some function calls just after a user logs in. How do i do that ?

Comment: I think ShZ's answer to this question is just what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990502/django-signal-when-user-logs-in

Comment: The second answer is preferable (if you are using 1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include a signal function. Whenever a user logs in, django fires a signal and your function will be called.

Refer the documentation on [auth signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#topics-auth-signals).

Comment: but `signals` are in django1.3 onwards right? I am currently using django1.2. What are the alternatives that i can use now ?