# How to delete objects after user logout?

Tags: django

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Drink(models.Model):
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

How to delete all Drink after user logout?

```
def delete_drink(request):
    user = request.user
    drink = Drink.objects.filter(owner=user)
    drink.delete()
```

Comment: A Signal coould fit your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990502/django-signal-when-user-logs-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do the trick:

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_out

def delete_drink(user):
    drink = Drink.objects.filter(owner=user)
    drink.delete()

def on_logout(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['user']:
        delete_drink(kwargs['user'])

user_logged_out.connect(on_logout, dispatch_uid="user_logout1")
```