# See if a user has just logged in?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'd like to display a message immediately after a user logs in. Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve including `django.contrib.auth` from the source and adding an `add_message` line there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the second answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990502/django-signal-when-user-logs-in). You can bind a login handler to the `user_logged_in` singal.