# Django: Call function once on login

Tags: python, django

I implemented Segment.io in my Django application. Once the user logs in I have to call `analytics.identify` once.

Currently, I call it every time on every page load as long `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` is the case. Do you have any idea how I can only call it once after the user logged in?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    analytics.identify('{{ user.email }}', {
      'first_name': user.first_name,
      'last_name': user.last_name,
    });
  {% endif %}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would implement this is:

- Change your 'login' view (the one that calls authenticate and login) to return a page, rather than a redirect.
- This page would have the script tag you've mentioned above, as well as a meta refresh redirect to the main page (or wherever you want the user to go)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie in your response object so that in the next page load you can avoid rendering the call to `analytics.identify` if that cookie is set:

```
def view(request):
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {'user_unidentified': 'user_identified' not in request.COOKIES}
    response = HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
    if 'user_identified' not in request.COOKIES:
        response.set_cookie('user_identified', '1')
    return response
```

Then in your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  {% if user_unidentified %}
    analytics.identify('{{ user.email }}', {
      'first_name': user.first_name,
      'last_name': user.last_name,
    });
  {% endif %}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use django signals for this. Put this code in your models.

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

def do_stuff(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    whatever...

user_logged_in.connect(do_stuff)
```

for more information, check out 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals and http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Original Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6109366/4349666